# Java - TaskTimer does not work with cellrenderer Jtable

Tags: java, jtable, timertask, tablecellrenderer

I have a JTable which contains list of IP address of the branches. I try to scan all IP address and paint the cell color according to the ping result. I use cellrenderer and Timertask but when I run the application freezed and paint the all cell after finished task, not like what i can see with TimerTask. I have learnt so many topic but i can not solve the problem.
Please give me an advise.
Thank you very much.
I give the code below:

```
 private void btn_kiemtraActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

            // TODO add your handling code here:
        timertask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {                          
                try {
                    kiemtra();
                } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Monitor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } finally {
                    tm.cancel();
                    tm.purge(); 
                    }
            }

        };
        tm.schedule(timertask, new Date());
}


public void kiemtra() throws IOException, UnknownHostException, InterruptedException {
    CellRenderer mcr = new CellRenderer();
    TableColumnModel columnModel = table_donvi.getColumnModel();
                for (int i = 3 ; i<=4; i++){
                    columnModel.getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(mcr);
                }
}

public Boolean rs (String cmd_ping) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, InterruptedException {
            Process p1 = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd_ping);
            int returnVal = p1.waitFor();
            boolean inet = (returnVal==0);
            return inet;
}


public class CellRenderer extends javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public java.awt.Component getTableCellRendererComponent(javax.swing.JTable table, java.lang.Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        java.awt.Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            String ping = "ping " +table.getValueAt(row, column).toString();
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                cellComponent.setBackground(java.awt.Color.YELLOW);
                                                table.repaint();
                                            }
                                        });  
            //System.out.println(ping);
        try {
            if (rs(ping)== true) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                cellComponent.setBackground(java.awt.Color.GREEN);
                                                table.repaint();
                                            }
                                        });  

            }
            else {
               SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                cellComponent.setBackground(java.awt.Color.RED);
                                                table.repaint();
                                            }
                                        });  
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Monitor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Monitor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return cellComponent;
        }
}
```

Comment: Use a SwingWorker or a Swing Timer and not a TimerTask

Comment: Thank you for your reply. @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: I am sory but I cant find some problem semilar to mine. I try to change to Swing Timer but it still not works. When I click the button nothing happen but when i active app (minimize, click mouse) then it run but freezed. Please help me, i dont know what problem i made. Here is the code i change:

Comment: private void btn_kiemtraActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        ActionListener action = new ActionListener()
        {   
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                                    kiemtra();
        };
        timer = new Timer(1000, action);
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();
    }

Comment: Then you likely have a long-running task being run on the event thread -- use a SwingWorker. Please read [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your enthusiasm. I try to learn more about your susgestion